# Цикл для List<String>.У элементов название последнего экземпляра в списке

Tags: java, android

Есть следующее:

```
List<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
for(String string : name)
{
  item.setTitle(string);
  array_dynamic.add(item);
}
```

На выходе я имею все элементы, но они - одинаковые, с названием последнего, а нужно -аутентичные. Как правильно написать цикл?

Comment: кто такие `array_dynamic` и `item` ?

Comment: Создавай item в цикле

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по всему вы просто один и тот же объект исползуете в цикле, каждую итерацию ему присваиваете новый `title` и добавляете его в некий список. В итоге у вас некий список содержит множество ссылок на один и тот же объект.

Вам надо создавать/использовать каждый раз новый объект. Как-то так:

```
for(String string : name) {
  Item item = new Item();
  item.setTitle(string);
  array_dynamic.add(item);
}
```

Comment: Благодарочка)).